# display an error message with a ModelForm Django (Python)

Tags: python, django-forms

Good morning,
I overload the save method of my ModelForm so that if the quantity is greater than the stock, the form is not saved.
But can I make an error message appear in my template in this case?
THANKS

forms.py :

````
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # je modifie le widget utilisé
    # modifier la qté dans le panier :
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(max_value=100, min_value=1)
    # supprimer un article du panier :
    delete = forms.BooleanField(initial=False, required=False, label='supprimer')

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ["quantity", 'delete']

    # relier le delete avec save
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # récupérer les données de mon formulaire :
        # avec cleaned_data qui est un dictionnaire, données de mon formulaire après qu'il ait été validé
        if self.cleaned_data['delete']:
            # if self.cleaned_data['delete'] is True:
            return self.instance.delete()
        if self.cleaned_data['quantity'] > self.instance.ticket.stock:
            return None

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)```

views.py :
````

```
    def cart(request):
        user = request.user
    
        cart = user.cart
    
        total_orders = Order.total(user=user)
    
        orders = cart.orders.all()
    
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/ref/forms/models/
        # créer une classe depuis modelformset_factory
        OrderFormSet = modelformset_factory(Order, form=OrderForm, extra=0)
        # puis créer une instance
        formset = OrderFormSet(queryset=orders)
    
        if request.method == "POST":
            formset = OrderFormSet(request.POST, queryset=orders)
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()
                if orders.count() == 0:
                    cart.delete()
                    return redirect('index')
                return redirect('store:cart')
    
        return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context={"forms": formset,
                                                           "user": user, "total": total_orders}

)
```

```
Currently I have no error message but just the form that does not save.
Thks
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go another route: Show the form if quantity is smaller than stock; don't show the form but some information if quantity is larger than stock.

But since you asked for the other solution, here you go:

```py
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(max_value=100, min_value=1)
    delete = forms.BooleanField(initial=False, required=False, label='supprimer')

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ["quantity", 'delete']

    def clean_quantity(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['quantity']
        if data > self.instance.ticket.stock:
            raise ValidationError("Quantity greater than stock!")
        return data

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.cleaned_data['delete']:
            return self.instance.delete()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)

This will simply fail the validation procedure and your view is going to take the route when `form.is_valid()` is `False`.